# 'safe' insert on heavy load lead to PK violation

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, race-condition, postgresql-9.4

I'm working on a big partitioned table (count around 0.5 TB & 5 x10^9 lines...) on Postgresql 9.4. This table grow by a good 8 x10^6 lines every day and face a heavy read/write use.

I need to fill the gaps of missing minutes that can happen with partial insert. I do this with the following query :

```
INSERT INTO huge_partitioned_table(id, date_gmt, date_local)
SELECT 
    to_do.id AS id,
    seq.seq AT TIME ZONE to_do.tz_lib AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS date_gmt,
    seq.seq AS date_local
FROM to_do
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL
        generate_series(
            to_do.date_needed::timestamp,
            to_do.date_needed::timestamp + INTERVAL '1439 minutes',
            INTERVAL '1 minute'
        ) seq
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM huge_partitioned_table hpt
    WHERE 
        to_do.id = hpt.id
        AND date_gmt = hpt.date_gmt
)
;
```

But It's the second time I get a **PK violation on my `PK(id, date_gmt)`, as an insert with the missing minutes was done at the same time this query was running**.

Is there a way to avoid PK violation in this case ? (The `on duplicate key do nothing` of pg 9.5 would be a perfect fit, but we can't update just for this)

The solution with a rule to ignore every `duplicate key` is not really good either, as working with time zone mean we do some real mistake and want to hit the PK FAIL in then...

Comment: How many rows you are inserting this way and how often you do it? I'm assuming that locking table or halting traffic on it is not an option.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński I'm inserting around 1M of missing minute with this insert, and I want to do it more than 10 time a day. Locking may be a solution as it's an ODS database and I'm aware that for concurrent write we don't have thousands ways to do it...

Comment: `AND date_gmt = hpt.date_gmt` -->> `AND seq.seq = hpt.date_gmt` (plus the AT TIME ZONE stuff) not fully qualified references default to the innermost scope.

Comment: @joop I was using the `seq AT...` when having the PK violation, and after some try it seem that the `date_gmt = hpt.date_gmt` refer at the alias and not the inner.

Comment: To be sure: fully qualify it. (or check the query plan...)

Comment: you can wrap it up to plpgsq and add exception handling?..instead of using global rule

Comment: @VaoTsun the exception handling will fail the full `insert into select` if I'm not mistaken ? I can't go with a full rollback of the batch for a few insert on fail :/

Comment: I got your thought - it will not perform insert for the whole select - yes

Comment: of course looping through the record and inserting rows one by one with `23505` handling is not an option?.. it would be slow of course

Comment: @VaoTsun You got it, I run a single big `insert into select`; I'm inserting 1M row ten time a day with this, so putting them one by one is out of the question yes :/

Comment: well - `where not exist` will not be atomic with your insert. and you can't `select for update` inside it - because you want NOT exist. So I believe its either upgrade and UPSERT or loop with exception handling

Comment: @VaoTsun well, for now, I think the lock table will be the best choice, even if I don't like it... :/  It's a waste that the `NOT EXISTS` when used in `INSERT INTO SELECT` don't get a lock to make it work on an atomic level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some tests, I'll go with an [explicit table write lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html) on the table :

```
LOCK TABLE huge_partitioned_table IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

> **SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE**
>
> Conflicts with the ROW EXCLUSIVE, SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This
>   mode **protects a table against concurrent data changes**, and is
>   self-exclusive so that only one session can hold it at a time.
>
> This lock mode is not automatically acquired by any PostgreSQL command.

This solution allow read while the lock is hold and put write on the wait list.